# Get color value programmatically when it's a reference (theme)

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

Consider this:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="theme_color">@color/theme_color_blue</item>
</style>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="theme_color" format="reference" />
```

**color.xml**

```
<color name="theme_color_blue">#ff0071d3</color>
```

So the **theme color** is referenced by the theme. How can I get the theme_color (reference) programmatically? Normally I would use `getResources().getColor()` but not in this case because it's referenced!

Answer (score 350, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.theme_color, typedValue, true);
@ColorInt int color = typedValue.data;
```

Also make sure to apply the theme to your Activity before calling this code.  Either use:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.BlueTheme"
```

in your manifest or call (before you call `setContentView(int)`):

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_BlueTheme)
```

in `onCreate()`.

I've tested it with your values and it worked perfectly.

Comment: thanks I can't try your solution yet cause I get an error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278244/cant-use-referenced-color-by-theme-in-drawable Maybe you have experience in this...

Comment: Anyway, with your solution I get a 0 value color (TypedValue{t=0x0/d=0x0})... I do not use declare-styleable, just a reference to the color

Comment: Do you apply the theme to you activity?

Comment: if theme_color is a reference to a ColorListState, how do you retrieve theme_color's "disabled" state color?

Comment: @Kimi sure it works, make sure that you have applied the theme

Comment: No it's not. At least not for my case. And I'm sure I've applied the theme programmatically. Anyway, I turn to use another way to get values.

Comment: Yes it does. If it doesn't work for you you're not doing it right. Post a question with code if you want a working solution.

Comment: If you don't want to apply the theme to the activity, you can create a `ContextThemeWrapper` using the theme id and then retrieve the theme from that.

Comment: @TedHopp, how do you get the theme id?

Comment: This method works in android X (material designing)

Comment: This method doesn't work if `theme_color` references a `ColorStateList`: you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49361848) to get default color or `AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, typedValue.resourceId)` to get `ColorStateList` object.

Comment: Now built in. The following is equivalent: `MaterialColors.getColor(context, R.attr.colorError, Color.GRAY)`

Answer (score 109):

We can use the utility class provided by Material Design library:

```
int color = MaterialColors.getColor(context, R.attr.theme_color, Color.BLACK)
```

NOTE: `Color.BLACK` is the default color in case the attribute supplied to the u

Comment: The best answer out of all

Comment: For sure using the MaterialColors utility class is the recommended way.
Even is possible to get theme color base on a view:
`val primaryColor = MaterialColors.getColor(view, R.attr.colorPrimary)`

Comment: This should be an accepted answer now in 2021

Comment: In my case "android.R.attr.textColorSecondary" for example is not working. Its just transparent. But the default color is not used, so i am stuck with this problem.  Any help?

Comment: @tzanke check your styles, mby you didnt declare `android:textColorSecondary`, not `textColorSecondary`. also make sure that the context had applied that style

Answer (score 92):

To add to the accepted answer, if you're using kotlin.

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorFromAttr(
    @AttrRes attrColor: Int,
    typedValue: TypedValue = TypedValue(),
    resolveRefs: Boolean = true
): Int {
    theme.resolveAttribute(attrColor, typedValue, resolveRefs)
    return typedValue.data
}
```

and then in your activity you can do

`textView.setTextColor(getColorFromAttr(R.attr.color))`

Comment: oook, thanks for the "integration". I'm not using kotlin but it's interesting.

Comment: Well it makes TypedValue visible to the outside world. And for colors you always want to resolve referential declarations, so I have this:
`@ColorInt fun Context.getThemeColor(@AttrRes attribute: Int) = TypedValue().let {
    theme.resolveAttribute(attribute, it, true);
    it.data
}`
(poorly formatted here but it's ok)

Comment: Usage would be like this: `val errorColor = context.getThemeColor(R.attr.colorError)`

Comment: More universal way, which also retrieves default value for a `ColorStateList`: `@ColorInt fun Context.getThemeColor(@AttrRes attribute: Int) = obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attribute)).use { it.getColor(0, Color.MAGENTA) }` (from [Nick Butcher](https://youtu.be/Owkf8DhAOSo?t=645))

Comment: Ultimate way, which retrieves the whole `ColorStateList`, even if it references another theme attributes: `fun Context.getThemeColor(@AttrRes attribute: Int): ColorStateList = TypedValue().let { theme.resolveAttribute(attribute, it, true); AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, it.resourceId) }` (single colors will be wrapped in a `ColorStateList` too).

Comment: Where do you actually need to place the "Context.getColorFromAttr" function declaration in order for this snippet to work?

Answer (score 32):

## `2021/January/8`

If you want to get color from theme attributes, use the following steps.

Create a variable my_color and store the color from theme attributes as,

```
val my_color = MaterialColors.getColor(<VIEWOBJECT>, R.attr.<YOUATRRIBUTENAME>)
```

**In place of `<VIEWOBJECT>`, pass a view object where you want to use the color, (behind the scenes it's just used to get the context as `<VIEWOBJECT>.getContext()` so that it can access resource i.e theme attribute values) . In place of `<YOURATTRIBUTENAME>`, use the name of the atrribute that you want to access**

**Example 1:**

If you want want to get color referenced by theme attributes from certain activity.
Create a variable that represents a view object on which you want to use the color.
Here i have a textView in my activity, i'll just reference its object inside `textview` variable and pass it to the `getColor` method and behind the scenes it'll use that object to just get the context, so that it can access theme attribute values

```
val textview: TextView = findViewById(R.id.mytextview)
val my_color = MaterialColors.getColor(textView, R.attr<YOURATTRIBUTENAME>)
```

**Example 2 :**

If you want to get color from theme attributes inside a custom view then just use,

```
val my_color = MaterialColors.getColor(this, R.attr.<YOUATRRIBUTENAME>)
```

Inside a custom view `this` refers to the object of the custom view, which is in fact a view object.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me:

```
int[] attrs = {R.attr.my_attribute};
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int color = ta.getResourceId(0, android.R.color.black);
ta.recycle();
```

if you want to get the hexstring out of it:

```
Integer.toHexString(color)
```

Comment: This should return a ColorRes, not a ColorInt.

Comment: I ended up using this with getColorResource(color) and not calling recycle.

Answer (score 14):

Add this to your build.gradle (app):

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
```

And add this extension function somewhere in your code:

```
import androidx.core.content.res.use

@ColorInt
@SuppressLint("Recycle")
fun Context.themeColor(
    @AttrRes themeAttrId: Int
): Int {
    return obtainStyledAttributes(
        intArrayOf(themeAttrId)
    ).use {
        it.getColor(0, Color.MAGENTA)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to get color from `android.R.attr.textColorSecondary` reference and only this solution worked. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I use this kotlin extension

```kotlin
@ColorInt
fun Context.getColorFromAttr( @AttrRes attrColor: Int
): Int {
    val typedArray = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attrColor))
    val textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, 0)
    typedArray.recycle()
    return textColor
}
```

sample

```kotlin
getColorFromAttr(android.R.attr.textColorSecondary)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get multiple colors you can use:

```
int[] attrs = {R.attr.customAttr, android.R.attr.textColorSecondary, 
        android.R.attr.textColorPrimaryInverse};
Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
TypedArray ta = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);

int[] colors = new int[attrs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
    colors[i] = ta.getColor(i, 0);
}

ta.recycle();
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for reference to a drawable you should use `false` in `resolveRefs`

`theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.some_drawable, typedValue, **false**);`

Comment: Whats the variable typedValue in reference to?

Comment: Whats the variable theme.* in reference to?

Answer (score 1):

With me it only worked using `ContextCompat` and the `typedValue.resourceId`

As proposed in this question: [How to get a value of color attribute programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361702/how-to-get-a-value-of-color-attribute-programmatically)

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlNormal, typedValue, true);
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)
```

Comment: idk why returns -1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise Java utility method that takes multiple attributes and return an array of color integers.  :)

```
/**
 * @param context    Pass the activity context, not the application context
 * @param attrFields The attribute references to be resolved
 * @return int array of color values
 */
@ColorInt
static int[] getColorsFromAttrs(Context context, @AttrRes int... attrFields) {
    int length = attrFields.length;
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

    @ColorInt int[] colorValues = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        @AttrRes int attr = attrFields[i];
        theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true);
        colorValues[i] = typedValue.data;
    }

    return colorValues;
}
```

Comment: Java is better than Kotlin for this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Oh, I honestly do not know. I shared my code since I knew it would come in handy to someone out there! I do not know Kotlin and I presume that Kotlin wouldn't make it perform any better, maybe fewer lines of code!  :P