# Can't use referenced color (by theme) in drawable

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme

Consider:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="theme_color">@color/theme_color_blue</item>
</style>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="theme_color" format="reference" />
```

**color.xml**

```
<color name="theme_color_blue">#ff0071d3</color>
```

and finally the **drawable progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="2px"
                android:color="#ff515151" />

            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="?attr/theme_color" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

when using progress bar drawable:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarStartup"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

**I get a runtime error**. It seems Android can't get the color theme.

```
06-24 16:35:57.032: E/AndroidRuntime(3493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx.activities.startup.ActivityStartup}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar


06-24 16:45:32.265: E/AndroidRuntime(9901): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010000 a=-1}
```

Comment: This line @style/android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Which line coresponds to line #33?

Comment: <ProgressBar, it's not very precise in this case...

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Eclipse sometimes messes up the ids.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this seems to be a known problem. But there is a workaround. Instead of using `?attr` referenced colors like you described, create several drawables (as many as the different colors you have), let each call its colors directly. On the theme level, reference to the drawables themselves depending on the theme. It works that way.

Update:

On Lollipop, you can tint the drawable in XML. To cover pre-Lollipop, you can simply call this for all your drawables in question (thanks to the newer versions of the appcompat library):

```
public void setDrawableColor(Drawable d, int color) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(d.mutate(), color);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think he only has two themes? If he has 200 themes, I don't see how your answer is correct. I think the real point of your answer is: You cannot single source the color in this use case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still the only workaround available, short of using Lollipop only where you can color your drawables. I have 12+ themes in one of my apps and yes, it's a PITA to have so many variants for the drawables but that's how it works. But I changed the wording to say more than two if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<attr name="theme_color" format="integer"/>`