# How to get a value of color attribute programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources, android-theme

When I use `resolveAttribute()` to find out a color value of `?attr/colorControlNormal`, I got `236`:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlNormal, typedValue, true);
int color = typedValue.data;
// 236
```

---

But when I use an XML layout with the following `TextView` element:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
  style="?android:attr/textAppearance"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal"
  android:text="@null" />
```

...and the following Java code:

```
View textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
int color = ((TextView) textView).getCurrentTextColor();
// -1979711488
```

I got a color value of `-1979711488`

---

Why those results vary? I expected to get same color values, but they are not.

The second approach (I believe) returns a correct color value. Why is  my first approach wrong?

I would prefer to obtain the color value of `?attr/colorControlNormal` without a need of using actual element. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you see on the `logcat` when you `Log.d` the value of `typedValue.coerceToString()`?

Comment: @pskink `res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml`

Comment: and what about simple `typedValue.toString()`?

Comment: @pskink `TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0xec "res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml" a=1 r=0x10601e8}`

Comment: see https://mbcdev.com/2017/01/16/resolving-android-theme-colours-programmatically/

Comment: Why is `resolveAttribute` preferable to just `getColor`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky - the idea is to get the color used in the theme

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe instead of this:

```
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlNormal, typedValue, true);
    int color = typedValue.data;
```

You should do this:

```
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlNormal, typedValue, true);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)
```

Comment: Is there some similar way to get a font size for `?android:attr/textAppearance` style? or a font color for `?android:attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` style? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Use `obtainStyledAttributes` passing down `android.R.attr.textAppearance`. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48138524/1083957).

Comment: Styles contain many attributes, I assume. How can I use that with `ta.getResourceId`? What index should I use to get color and what index to get font-size? I am confused. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: I assume this way: if you have specified, that you want to get resources (a, b, c), then for getting a's value, you have to refer to index 0, c-s value will be index 2. If you know, that c is a color, than you should perform `typedArray.getColor(2, 0)`.

Comment: Nope, `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 0 to color: type=0x1`

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, according to @azizbekian answer, to do it you could do something like this:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
theme.resolveAttribute(com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorControlNormal, typedValue, true)
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct I think, check with it

HEX

```
Integer intColor = -1979711488138;
String hexColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(intColor).substring(2);
```

or

```
int color = getCurrentTextColor();
int a = Color.alpha(color);
int r = Color.red(color);
int g = Color.green(color);
int b = Color.blue(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin you can do the following to get the color:

```
val color = TypedValue().let {
    requireContext().theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorControlNormal, it, true)
    requireContext().getColor(it.resourceId)
}
```