# setTextAppearance using theme attributes programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I have custom textAppearance defined in my themes. My Theme looks like this

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
.....
<item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MySpark.Headline3</item>
.....
</style>
```

Here is the style `TextAppearance.MyApp.Headline3`

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MyApp.Headline3" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3">
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/avenir_next_demi</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left|top</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnSurface</item>
    </style>
```

**Works for XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_product_description"/>
```

**WORKS for programmatically referencing style**

```
textView.setTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MyApp_Headline3)
```

**DOESN'T WORK FOR** 
When I want to apply textAppearance programmatically using attr, I couldn't find a way yet for something like this.

`textView.setTextAppearance(R.attr.textAppearanceHeadline3)`

I would like to use attr which helps me in switching different themes.

Comment: I think you might be looking to [resolve theme attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277714/5288316). In this case the `TypedValue` data is the text appearance resource ID.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm using `TypedValue` approach for colours. I don't think you can use the same approach to textAppearance as it has many properties under it.

Comment: There's another approach in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39377287/5288316) with `obtainStyledAttributes`. What you resolve is always the resource ID (an integer) referenced by the attribute, which is then used by the TextView to resolve more attributes. (see the [source](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/602faa961aed934a4cd77913db7fc9e6ccf2e25b/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3821))

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for that. With this approach, I have to read all the attributes inside `textAppearance` and apply to textview. This is pretty error-prone. If I add/delete any properties in style, I have to remember and change in my class as well. This seems like an easy miss.

Comment: See my answer, I hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every Android resource has an integer ID associated to it. Attributes only reference the resource ID, not the resource itself. To resolve this resource ID from an attribute, you use `Context.obtainStyledAttributes` with an array of attributes:

```
val attrs = intArrayOf(R.attr.myTextAppearance)       // The array of attributes we're interested in.
val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs)        // Get the value referenced by the attributes in the array
val resId = ta.getResourceId(0, 0)                    // The first 0 is the index in the 'attrs' array.
ta.recycle()                                          // Don't forget that! You can also use TypedArray.use { } extensions from android KTX.
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, resId)     // Utility method to set text appearance for all SDK versions
```

A text appearance is just a regular style which has a higher priority when applied on the text view, and only text attributes are used. That's what I wanted to show when I linked the TextView source code.

When you pass a resource ID to `setTextAppearance`, the TextView resolves all the attributes values in the `TextAppearance` styleable (basically a list of attributes), storing the values in a TypedArray, then reads and applies them.

Using `resolveAttribute` like I first suggested is similar to using `obtainStyledAttributes`, but the TypedValue is set automatically to the attribute value, in this case a resource ID, without having to call `getResourceId`.

Comment: Wow. Such a good explanation. I was thinking text appearance is a bit different. Thanks for explaining. It worked