# set attribute format color programmatically android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an attributes file in my resources where i store a bunch of different colours, and have been settings them in xml like so:

```
android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
```

Say I have a TextView called textView in my Java. How can I do the same task programmatically?

I tried with this

```
fun fetchAttr(@AttrRes attr: Int, vararg args: Any?): Int {
    val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attr))
    val textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, 0)
    typedArray.recycle()
    return textColor
}

textview.fetchAttr(android.R.attr.black)
```

but when i use my attr uiColorPrimaryRipple in my attrTest.xml like this :

```
<attr name="uiColorPrimaryRipple" format="color" />
```

and i put :

```
    textview.fetchAttr(R.attr.uiColorPrimaryRipple)
```

does not work for me

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51561533/15298643

Comment: I check it but does not work, i think i attr (theme) of android API.
i want make work my attr , have you any idea ?