# Get theme's primaryColor in an Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-theme

I am using a determinate circular progress indicator in my Fragment.
Depending on the progress, the progress indicator shall have different colors. So, if the progress is 100%, it shall turn red, otherwise it is blue.

In a previous project I successfully used the following code, which is not working anymore - and I cannot find the reason for it.

The code was originally taken from this post: [Get color value programmatically when it's a reference (theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277618/get-color-value-programmatically-when-its-a-reference-theme)

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = getContext().getTheme();
@ColorInt int color;
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
color = typedValue.data;
circularProgressIndicator.setIndicatorColor(color);
```

The error already pops up during building. [image: Error message in build]

The R class I am using is the right one --> import *mypackage*.R;

The theme is set properly (or even too often!?)

- in the Manifest file
- in the Main Activity Layout XML
- in the Main Activity before "setContentView)
- in the Fragment Layout XML

Does anybody have an idea why I cannot select the color from my theme this way?

I cannot set the the color directly from R.color as it depends on day/night mode.
An other approach would be to set different styles for the progress indicator in code, but it seems that the class CircularProgressIndicator is not offering this as for example a TextView does.

Colors XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ReminderBlue">#00337A</color>
    <color name="ReminderError">#B00020</color>
...
</resources>
```

Theme.XML

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Theme.Reminder" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ReminderBlue</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/ReminderError</item>
        .....
    </style>
```

FragmentLayout.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Reminder"
    tools:context=".activities.fragments.MainFragment">
```

Comment: Have you added style to styles.xml and color to attrs.xml

Comment: The color is defined in colors.xml.

In the themes.xml I am using one of the color as the primaryColor. 

And in the activity I am using my own theme.