# How to get value from android.R.attr.* in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In old views I used `android:padding="?dialogPreferredPadding"` which is

```
<!-- Preferred padding for dialog content. -->
<attr name="dialogPreferredPadding" format="dimension" />
```

I can find this attribute in code by `android.R.attr.dialogPreferredPadding` but I do not know how can I get the value of this attribute in Jetpack Compose?

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding( <use dialogPreferredPadding here> )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get color value programmatically when it's a reference (theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277618/get-color-value-programmatically-when-its-a-reference-theme)

Comment: It's little different but it helped me. Thank you.