# Android Color Theme get Background Color

Tags: android, material-design, background-color, android-theme

I need to get the Color of the default background color of the App in Code.

up until now i used R.attr.colorSurface to get this, but somehow lately this gives me the incorrect color on some devices.

when i use this function, I'm getting a dark color in light theme and blue in dark theme

```
public static int getThemeColor2(Context context, int android_r)
{
    if(context == null)
        return 0x000000;
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277714/1683382
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(android_r, typedValue, true);
    @ColorInt int color = typedValue.data;
    return color;
}
```

when i use this code, I'm getting yellow-white in light and light pink in dark theme

```
MaterialColors.getColor(context, R.attr.colorSurface, Color.BLACK);
```

for all other theme colors i can use R.attr like R.attr.colorPrimary, R.attr.colorSecondary etc but I'm just not able to get the background color correctly now matter what i try.

what is the correct way to get this color?

Some notes:

R.attr.backgroundColor gives me 0x000000

colorOnBackground exists but colorBackground does not?

what is colorBackgroundFloating ?

is it just me, or is the whole Theme Color a total mess. There is no complete overview and multiple functions that gives you different results

Comment: I'm a little surprised that i have not gotten an answer for such a basic question. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly?